dhcp6 server config problems when match if option dhcp6.vendor-class
The complete content of the client's Vendor Class data is as follows:
Vendor Class
Option: Vendor Class (16)
Length: 38
Value: 000001570020505845436c69656e743a417263683a303030...
Enterprise ID: Intel Corporation (343)
vendor-class-data: PXEClient:Arch:00011:UNDI:003016

The DHCPv6 configuration is as below. Why is it not matching "PXEClient:Arch:00011"?
option dhcp6.vendor-class code 16 = text;
subnet6 3ffe:501:ffff:9::/64
{
    range6 3ffe:501:ffff:9::3 3ffe:501:ffff:9::ffff;
    if substring(option dhcp6.vendor-class, 0, 20) = "PXEClient:Arch:00011" {
        option dhcp6.bootfile-url "tftp://[3ffe:501:ffff:1:1:0:d:202]/_H3CCustomized_ZBB_ARM.efi";
    }
}

